Galois group of $x=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$ for $b$ and $a^2-b$ not perfect squares
Suppose we want to find the Galois group of $x=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ for $b$ is not a perfect square $($EDIT: and I want $a^2-b$ to also not be a perfect square$)$. I've done this enough times to recognize that the Galois group is isomorphic to the Klein-$4$ group but I struggle to officially show it. So I do my best:
Doing algebra to both sides of $x=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$, we eventually obtain that $x$ is the root of the polynomial $p(x) = x^4-2ax^2+(a^2-b)$. As $p(x)$ is even, then $- \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$ is also a root. If we make the substitution $u=x^2$, we have $q(u)= u^2-2au+a^2-b$ and we get as roots of $q(u)$ the values
$$u= \frac{2a}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{4a^2-4(a^2-b)}}{2} = a\pm \sqrt{b}$$
Undoing our subsitution, we have that the remaining two roots of $p(x)$ are $\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}$ and $-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}$. Now, the splitting field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ contains all four of these roots. As all four of these roots are not in $\mathbb{Q}$, then $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial $($Indeed, $p(x)$ cannot be the product of linear and cubic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ nor as the product of two quadratic polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ since degree $2$ or $3$ polynomials have irreducibility characterized by where their roots lie.$)$
So the Galois group $G$ has $|G| = [K:\mathbb{Q}] \mid 4! = 24$. Now, if $\sigma \in G$, then sigma permutes roots of irreducible polynomials so
$$\sigma \begin{cases} 
\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}} \mapsto \, \, \pm \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}} \\ 
-\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}} \mapsto  \, \, \pm \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}} \\ 
\sqrt{a - \sqrt{b}} \mapsto \hspace{0.4cm} ??? \\
-\sqrt{a - \sqrt{b}} \mapsto \hspace{0.4cm} ??? \\
\end{cases}$$
It's clear to me that the action that $\sigma$ has on the roots $\pm \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$ either fixes them or changes the sign of them. In this way, these two roots are locked in this small orbit of sorts. But what polynomial are the roots $\pm \sqrt{a - \sqrt{b}}$ assigned to in terms of the above diagram?
I think if I knew this, I would be able to finally establish formally that the Galois group indeed is isomorphic to the Klein-$4$ group.

@DanielSchepler Ah thank you for bringing that to my attention. I have updated the post so that I stipulate that $a^2-b$ is squarefree. I do want this to stick with the Klein-$4$ outcome

If I remember correctly, you don't necessarily have to have $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}} \mapsto \pm \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$, you could also have automorphisms with $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}} \mapsto \sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}$ for example.  In general, you have 4 choices for where to send $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$, and then based on that you have 2 choices for where to send $\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}$ (with the image of $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$ and its negation being ruled out).

@DanielSchepler sorry that's what I meant. I sometimes confuse those terms. I will change it to say perfect square

Although it appears that yet more hypotheses might be needed to get to a specific result.  For instance, my calculations in Sage indicate that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}})$ has Galois group of order 8, while $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$ has Galois group of order 4 (and one of the links on the right shows in the latter case, the Galois group is $C_4$).

The number $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$ is a root of $X^4 - 2aX^2 + a^2 - b$.
The following theorem describes the Galois group of any irreducible quartic having the form $X^4 + AX^2 + B$ in characteristic $0$ in terms of properties involving the coefficients $A$ and $B$. I write $V$ for the Klein $4$-group (as $V$ is the first letter in the German word for four).
Theorem. Let $f(X) = X^4 + AX^2 + B$ be irreducible in $K[X]$, where $K$ is a field with characteristic not equal to $2$. The Galois group $G_f$ of $f(X)$ over $K$ is $V$, $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$, or $D_4$ according to the following conditions:
(1) $G_f = V$ if $B = \Box$ in $K$,
(2) $G_f = \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ if $(A^2 − 4B)B = \Box$ in $K$,
(3) $G_f = D_4$ if $B \not= \Box$ in $K$ and $(A^2 − 4B)B \not= \Box$ in $K$.
Proof. See Corollary 4.5 here.
Note the three conditions in the theorem are complementary, so the conditions to make (1), (2), and (3) hold are each necessary and sufficient. In your setting, $A = -2a$ and $B = a^2 - b$, so $A^2 - 4B = 4b$.  Thus
the group $G_f$ is determined by whether or not $a^2 - b$ and $b(a^2 - b)$ are squares in $K$:
(1) $G_f = V$ when $a^2 - b = \Box$ in $K$,
(2) $G_f = \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ when $b(a^2 - b) = \Box$ in $K$,
(3) $G_f = D_4$ otherwise.
You are asking what happens when $K = \mathbf Q$ and $b$ and $a^2 - b$ are not squares, but those two conditions are not adequate to single out one choice for $G_f$. All we can say for sure is that since $a^2 - b \not= \Box$ we have $G_f \not= V$, which exactly contradicts your certainty that $G_f$ is $V$ ("I've done this enough times to recognize that the Galois group is isomorphic to the Klein-4 group but I struggle to officially show it.") No wonder you've been having so much trouble: you have been trying to show $G_f$ has the one value that it can never have in the situation you're working in.
Between the other two options for $G_f$, each can occur: $G_f = \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ when $a = 2$ and $b = 2$, while $G_f = D_4$ when $a = 3$ and $b = 2$. Generically we'd expect $b(a^2 - b)$ not to be a square, so the option $G_f = D_4$ is going to happen in practice more often, but example can easily be written down where the other choice $G_f = \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ occurs and I already gave you one ($a=2$ and $b = 2$).

Very informative! May I ask what you mean by "$\square$?"

By $t = \Box$ or $t \not= \Box$ I mean $t$ is or is not a square!
